# How to download a file over HTTP?

Tags: python, http, urllib

I have a small utility that I use to download an MP3 file from a website on a schedule and then builds/updates a podcast XML file which I've added to iTunes.

The text processing that creates/updates the XML file is written in Python. However, I use wget inside a Windows `.bat` file to download the actual MP3 file. I would prefer to have the entire utility written in Python.

I struggled to find a way to actually download the file in Python, thus why I resorted to using `wget`.

So, how do I download the file using Python?

Comment: See also: [How to save an image locally using Python whose URL address I already know?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8286352/562769)

Comment: Many of the answers below are not a satisfactory replacement for `wget`. Among other things, `wget` (1) preserves timestamps (2) auto-determines filename from url, appending `.1` (etc.) if the file already exists (3) has many other options, some of which you may have put in your `.wgetrc`. If you want any of those, you have to implement them yourself in Python, but it's simpler to just invoke `wget` from Python.

Comment: Short solution for Python 3: `import urllib.request; s = urllib.request.urlopen('http://example.com/').read().decode()`

Comment: wget is still a better approach, if you need to automatically retrieve filename and timestamps and handling duplicating files as https://stackoverflow.com/users/4958/shreevatsar stated. 
If the urls are variables, one can still handle in python using subprocess.

Answer (score 564, accepted):

Use [`urllib.request.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.example.com/') as f:
    html = f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

This is the most basic way to use the library, minus any error handling. You can also do more complex stuff such as changing headers.

On Python 2, the method is in [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/')
html = response.read()
```

Comment: This won't work if there are spaces in the url you provide. In that case, you'll need to parse the url and urlencode the path.

Comment: Here is the Python 3 solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3

Comment: Just for reference. The way to urlencode the path is `urllib2.quote`

Comment: @JasonSundram: If there are spaces in it, it isn't a URI.

Comment: This does not work on windows with larger files. You need to read all blocks!

Comment: Or replace space with %20

Comment: Since it currently is the highest voted answer with non-deprecated code, it might be a good idea to show how to download binary files. `.decode('utf-8')` doesn't make sense for every file on the internet.

Comment: This link is quite useful: https://realpython.com/python-download-file-from-url/#downloading-a-large-file-in-a-streaming-fashion

Answer (score 1377):

One more, using [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request):

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.example.com/songs/mp3.mp3", "mp3.mp3")
```

(for Python 2 use `import urllib` and `urllib.urlretrieve`)

Comment: Oddly enough, this worked for me on Windows when the urllib2 method wouldn't. The urllib2 method worked on Mac, though.

Comment: Bug: file_size_dl += block_sz should be += len(buffer) since the last read is often not a full block_sz.  Also on windows you need to open the output file as "wb" if it isn't a text file.

Comment: Me too urllib and urllib2 didn't work but urlretrieve worked well, was getting frustrated - thanks :)

Comment: Wrap the whole thing (except the definition of file_name) with `if not os.path.isfile(file_name):` to avoid overwriting podcasts! useful when running it as a cronjob with the urls found in a .html file

Comment: I have a suggestion, using .format() instead of % string formatting and sys.stdout.write(): https://gist.github.com/3176958

Comment: for people who don't know, the second parameter of `urllib.urlretrieve` is the file it will be downloaded to.

Comment: This is a good example of how to start doing stream processing on a http response. I was looking for a way to do exactly that, and could not find it right away by looking at the docs. Thanks saved me some trouble.

Comment: Best Answer to this question. Is it possible to change block_size?

Comment: How did you came up with block_sz = 8192 ? is there an appropriate way to pick buffer size ?

Comment: Hey @PabloG ! i am having some problem in your 1st code. It can download the html file of page but not its css and js file. Please tell me how to do that. Anybody having the solution can reply.

Comment: @PabloG is it possible to download https contents?

Comment: meta is a http.client.HTTPMessage object and it has no getheaders() method.
Instead, change the line to: 
`file_size = int(dict(meta.items())['Content-Length'])` and it should work gloriously.

Comment: file_name = url.split('/')[-1] gives url encoded file name which is a problem if the file name has special characters (space, + etc..). Using urllib.parse.unquote gives the correct file name.
from urllib.parse import unquote
file_name = unquote(file_name')

Comment: According to the documentation, `urllib.request.urlretrieve` is a "legacy interface" and "might become deprecated in the future. https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface

Comment: Exception handling is necessary: try for except `urllib.error.URLError`

Comment: Does `urlretrieve` silently overwrites the local file if it exists? The documentation doesn't mention this.

Comment: in python3.11 they still only say it "might become deprecated in the future". I think that actually makes it a very stable thing to rely on, despite the name legacy-interface. Even if they do remove it there will be at least a year-long transition in which warnings will guide you towards another oneliner.

Answer (score 426):

In 2012, use the [python requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/)

```
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> url = "http://download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip"
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> print len(r.content)
10485760
```

You can run `pip install requests` to get it.

Requests has many advantages over the alternatives because the API is much simpler. This is especially true if you have to do authentication. urllib and urllib2 are pretty unintuitive and painful in this case.

---

2015-12-30

People have expressed admiration for the progress bar. It's cool, sure. There are several off-the-shelf solutions now, including `tqdm`:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests

url = "http://download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open("10MB", "wb") as handle:
    for data in tqdm(response.iter_content()):
        handle.write(data)
```

This is essentially the implementation @kvance described 30 months ago.

Comment: how do I save or extract if the zip file is actually a folder with many files in it?

Comment: How does this handle large files, does everything get stored into memory or can this be written to a file without large memory requirement?

Comment: It is possible to stream large files by setting stream=True in the request.  You can then call iter_content() on the response to read a chunk at a time.

Comment: @kvance: I did not know that. This option became known as `stream` in v1.0.0, AFAICT. It seems to have been `prefetch` in earlier versions, but I have not dug into the source code enough. Try: `git clone git@github.com:kennethreitz/requests.git && git log -S"self.stream" --source --all`

Comment: Why would a url library need to have a file unzip facility? Read the file from the url, save it and then unzip it in whatever way floats your boat. Also a zip file is not a 'folder' like it shows in windows, Its a file.

Comment: What would be the difference between `r.content` and `r.text`?

Comment: @Ali: `r.text`: For text or unicode content. Returned as unicode. `r.content`: For binary content. Returned as bytes. Read about it here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Comment: Progress bar not look nice.

Comment: I think a `chunk_size` argument is desirable along with `stream=True`. The default `chunk_size` is `1`, which means, each chunk could be as small as `1` byte and so is very inefficient.

Comment: What does 2012 mean in Python versions?

Comment: @lindhe Are you using a python version earlier than 2.7? If not, you should be able to run requests on any version you come across.

Comment: Please consider not using requests for any serious application, it's not thead-safe and has a memory-leak issue.

Comment: @ospider: Do you have more info? It might still be okay if it's a one-off solution. E.g. your script expects a json in input folder. If it isn't there, download it, and forget about requests next time you run the script.

Comment: `for data in tqdm(response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), unit='kB'):` will download and write the file in chunk, and show the correct unit in the progress bar.

Comment: This link is quite useful. https://realpython.com/python-download-file-from-url/#downloading-a-large-file-in-a-streaming-fashion

Answer (score 172):

```py
import urllib2
mp3file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/songs/mp3.mp3")
with open('test.mp3','wb') as output:
  output.write(mp3file.read())
```

The `wb` in `open('test.mp3','wb')` opens a file (and erases any existing file) in binary mode so you can save data with it instead of just text.

Comment: The disadvantage of this solution is, that the entire file is loaded into ram before saved to disk, just something to keep in mind if using this for large files on a small system like a router with limited ram.

Comment: @tripplet so how would we fix that?

Comment: To avoid reading the whole file into memory, try passing an argument to `file.read` that is the number of bytes to read. See: https://gist.github.com/hughdbrown/c145b8385a2afa6570e2

Comment: @hughdbrown I found your script useful, but have one question: can I use the file for post-processing? suppose I download a jpg file that I want to process with OpenCV, can I use the 'data' variable to keep working? or do I have to read it again from the downloaded file?

Comment: Use `shutil.copyfileobj(mp3file, output)` instead.

Answer (score 163):

#### Python 3

- [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen)

  ```
  import urllib.request
  response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.example.com/')
  html = response.read()
  ```
- [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve)

  ```
  import urllib.request
  urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.example.com/songs/mp3.mp3', 'mp3.mp3')
  ```

  **Note:** According to the documentation, `urllib.request.urlretrieve` is a "legacy interface" and "might become deprecated in the future" (thanks [gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python/31857152?noredirect=1#comment107731047_31857152))

#### Python 2

- [`urllib2.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) (thanks [Corey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22682/399105))

  ```
  import urllib2
  response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/')
  html = response.read()
  ```
- [`urllib.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) (thanks [PabloG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776/399105))

  ```
  import urllib
  urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.example.com/songs/mp3.mp3', 'mp3.mp3')
  ```

Comment: It sure took a while, but there, finally is the easy straightforward api I expect from a python stdlib :)

Comment: Very nice answer for python3, see also https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve

Comment: @EdouardThiel If you click on `urllib.request.urlretrieve` above it'll bring you to that exact link. Cheers!

Comment: `urllib.request.urlretrieve` is documented as a "legacy interface" and "might become deprecated in the future".

Comment: You should mention that you are getting a bunch of bytes that need to be handled after that.

Answer (score 46):

```
import os,requests
def download(url):
    get_response = requests.get(url,stream=True)
    file_name  = url.split("/")[-1]
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in get_response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)


download("https://example.com/example.jpg")
```

Comment: Thanks, also, replace `with open(file_name,...` with `with open('thisname'...)` because it may throw an error

Answer (score 45):

use [wget module](https://pypi.org/project/wget/):

```
import wget
wget.download('url')
```

Comment: The repo seems to be removed.

Comment: project was moved to github, but then archived by its author

Answer (score 27):

An improved version of the PabloG code for Python 2/3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import ( division, absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals )

import sys, os, tempfile, logging

if sys.version_info >= (3,):
    import urllib.request as urllib2
    import urllib.parse as urlparse
else:
    import urllib2
    import urlparse

def download_file(url, dest=None):
    """ 
    Download and save a file specified by url to dest directory,
    """
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
    filename = os.path.basename(path)
    if not filename:
        filename = 'downloaded.file'
    if dest:
        filename = os.path.join(dest, filename)

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        meta = u.info()
        meta_func = meta.getheaders if hasattr(meta, 'getheaders') else meta.get_all
        meta_length = meta_func("Content-Length")
        file_size = None
        if meta_length:
            file_size = int(meta_length[0])
        print("Downloading: {0} Bytes: {1}".format(url, file_size))

        file_size_dl = 0
        block_sz = 8192
        while True:
            buffer = u.read(block_sz)
            if not buffer:
                break

            file_size_dl += len(buffer)
            f.write(buffer)

            status = "{0:16}".format(file_size_dl)
            if file_size:
                status += "   [{0:6.2f}%]".format(file_size_dl * 100 / file_size)
            status += chr(13)
            print(status, end="")
        print()

    return filename

if __name__ == "__main__":  # Only run if this file is called directly
    print("Testing with 10MB download")
    url = "http://download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip"
    filename = download_file(url)
    print(filename)
```

Comment: I would remove the parentheses from the first line, because it is not too old feature.

Answer (score 23):

Simple yet `Python 2 & Python 3` compatible way comes with `six` library:

```
from six.moves import urllib
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.example.com/songs/mp3.mp3", "mp3.mp3")
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it for 2+3 compatibility.

Answer (score 21):

Following are the most commonly used calls for downloading files in python:

1. `urllib.urlretrieve ('url_to_file', file_name)`
2. `urllib2.urlopen('url_to_file')`
3. `requests.get(url)`
4. `wget.download('url', file_name)`

Note: `urlopen` and `urlretrieve` are found to perform relatively bad with downloading large files (size > 500 MB). `requests.get` stores the file in-memory until download is complete.

Answer (score 20):

Wrote [wget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget) library in pure Python just for this purpose. It is pumped up `urlretrieve` with [these features](https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-wget/src/6859e7b4aba37cef57616111be890fb59631bc4c/wget.py?at=default#cl-330) as of version 2.0.

Comment: No option to save with custom filename ?

Comment: @Alex added -o FILENAME option to version 2.1

Comment: The progress bar does not appear when I use this module under Cygwin.

Comment: You should change from `-o` to `-O` to avoid confusion, as it is in GNU wget. Or at least both options should be valid.

Comment: @eric I am not sure that I want to make `wget.py` an in-place replacement for real `wget`. The `-o` already behaves differently - it is compatible with `curl` this way. Would a note in documentation help to resolve the issue? Or it is the essential feature for an utility with such name to be command line compatible?

Comment: @anatolytechtonik How can i save the file downloaded using wget?. Also how to turn off verification of SSL certificates?

Comment: @GautamKrishnaR `wget.py` saves file automatically. As for SSL checks, they are done by Python, so look how to disable it there or ask another question.

Comment: Is the library been supported in 2023? There is no homepage available on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget.

Answer (score 17):

In python3 you can use urllib3 and shutil libraires.
Download them by using pip or pip3 (Depending whether python3 is default or not)

```
pip3 install urllib3 shutil
```

Then run this code

```
import urllib.request
import shutil

url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/something.pdf"
output_file = "save_this_name.pdf"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(output_file, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

Note that you download `urllib3` but use `urllib` in code

Answer (score 15):

I agree with Corey, urllib2 is more complete than [urllib](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-urllib.html) and should likely be the module used if you want to do more complex things, but to make the answers more complete, urllib is a simpler module if you want just the basics:

```
import urllib
response = urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com/sound.mp3')
mp3 = response.read()
```

Will work fine. Or, if you don't want to deal with the "response" object you can call **read()** directly:

```
import urllib
mp3 = urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com/sound.mp3').read()
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have wget installed, you can use parallel_sync.

pip install parallel_sync

```
from parallel_sync import wget
urls = ['http://something.png', 'http://somthing.tar.gz', 'http://somthing.zip']
wget.download('/tmp', urls)
# or a single file:
wget.download('/tmp', urls[0], filenames='x.zip', extract=True)
```

Doc:
https://pythonhosted.org/parallel_sync/pages/examples.html

This is pretty powerful. It can download files in parallel, retry upon failure , and it can even download files on a remote machine.

Comment: Note this is for Linux only

Answer (score 9):

You can get the progress feedback with urlretrieve as well:

```
def report(blocknr, blocksize, size):
    current = blocknr*blocksize
    sys.stdout.write("\r{0:.2f}%".format(100.0*current/size))

def downloadFile(url):
    print "\n",url
    fname = url.split('/')[-1]
    print fname
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, fname, report)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use python **requests**

```
import os
import requests


outfile = os.path.join(SAVE_DIR, file_name)
response = requests.get(URL, stream=True)
with open(outfile,'wb') as output:
  output.write(response.content)
```

You can use **shutil**

```
import os
import requests
import shutil
 
outfile = os.path.join(SAVE_DIR, file_name)
response = requests.get(url, stream = True)
with open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
  shutil.copyfileobj(response.content, f)
```

- If you are downloading from restricted url, don't forget to include access token in headers

Answer (score 6):

Just for the sake of completeness, it is also possible to call any program for retrieving files using the `subprocess` package. Programs dedicated to retrieving files are more powerful than Python functions like `urlretrieve`. For example, [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) can download directories recursively (`-R`), can deal with FTP, redirects, HTTP proxies, can avoid re-downloading existing files (`-nc`), and [`aria2`](https://aria2.github.io/) can do multi-connection downloads which can potentially speed up your downloads.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['wget', '-O', 'example_output_file.html', 'https://example.com'])
```

In Jupyter Notebook, one can also call programs directly with the `!` syntax:

```
!wget -O example_output_file.html https://example.com
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Python Requests in 5 lines

```
import requests as req

remote_url = 'http://www.example.com/sound.mp3'
local_file_name = 'sound.mp3'

data = req.get(remote_url)

# Save file data to local copy
with open(local_file_name, 'wb')as file:
    file.write(data.content)
```

Now do something with the local copy of the remote file

Comment: Why go through the hassle of importing requests "as req" for just a single call of the package?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote the following, which works in vanilla Python 2 or Python 3.

---

```
import sys
try:
    import urllib.request
    python3 = True
except ImportError:
    import urllib2
    python3 = False


def progress_callback_simple(downloaded,total):
    sys.stdout.write(
        "\r" +
        (len(str(total))-len(str(downloaded)))*" " + str(downloaded) + "/%d"%total +
        " [%3.2f%%]"%(100.0*float(downloaded)/float(total))
    )
    sys.stdout.flush()

def download(srcurl, dstfilepath, progress_callback=None, block_size=8192):
    def _download_helper(response, out_file, file_size):
        if progress_callback!=None: progress_callback(0,file_size)
        if block_size == None:
            buffer = response.read()
            out_file.write(buffer)

            if progress_callback!=None: progress_callback(file_size,file_size)
        else:
            file_size_dl = 0
            while True:
                buffer = response.read(block_size)
                if not buffer: break

                file_size_dl += len(buffer)
                out_file.write(buffer)

                if progress_callback!=None: progress_callback(file_size_dl,file_size)
    with open(dstfilepath,"wb") as out_file:
        if python3:
            with urllib.request.urlopen(srcurl) as response:
                file_size = int(response.getheader("Content-Length"))
                _download_helper(response,out_file,file_size)
        else:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(srcurl)
            meta = response.info()
            file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
            _download_helper(response,out_file,file_size)

import traceback
try:
    download(
        "https://geometrian.com/data/programming/projects/glLib/glLib%20Reloaded%200.5.9/0.5.9.zip",
        "output.zip",
        progress_callback_simple
    )
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    input()
```

---

Notes:

- Supports a "progress bar" callback.
- Download is a 4 MB test .zip from my website.

Comment: works great, run it through jupyter got what i want  :-)

Answer (score 5):

If speed matters to you, I made a small performance test for the modules `urllib` and `wget`, and regarding `wget` I tried once with status bar and once without. I took three different 500MB files to test with (different files- to eliminate the chance that there is some caching going on under the hood). Tested on debian machine, with python2.

First, these are the results (they are similar in different runs):

```
$ python wget_test.py 
urlretrive_test : starting
urlretrive_test : 6.56
==============
wget_no_bar_test : starting
wget_no_bar_test : 7.20
==============
wget_with_bar_test : starting
100% [......................................................................] 541335552 / 541335552
wget_with_bar_test : 50.49
==============
```

The way I performed the test is using "profile" decorator. This is the full code:

```
import wget
import urllib
import time
from functools import wraps

def profile(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args):
        print func.__name__, ": starting"
        start = time.time()
        ret = func(*args)
        end = time.time()
        print func.__name__, ": {:.2f}".format(end - start)
        return ret
    return inner

url1 = 'http://host.com/500a.iso'
url2 = 'http://host.com/500b.iso'
url3 = 'http://host.com/500c.iso'

def do_nothing(*args):
    pass

@profile
def urlretrive_test(url):
    return urllib.urlretrieve(url)

@profile
def wget_no_bar_test(url):
    return wget.download(url, out='/tmp/', bar=do_nothing)

@profile
def wget_with_bar_test(url):
    return wget.download(url, out='/tmp/')

urlretrive_test(url1)
print '=============='
time.sleep(1)

wget_no_bar_test(url2)
print '=============='
time.sleep(1)

wget_with_bar_test(url3)
print '=============='
time.sleep(1)
```

`urllib` seems to be the fastest

Comment: There must be something completely horrible going on under the hood to make the bar increase the time so much.

Answer (score 4):

Source code can be:

```
import urllib
sock = urllib.urlopen("http://diveintopython.org/")
htmlSource = sock.read()                            
sock.close()                                        
print htmlSource
```

Answer (score 4):

urlretrieve and requests.get are simple, however the reality not.
I have fetched data for couple sites, including text and images, the above two probably solve most of the tasks. but for a more universal solution I suggest the use of urlopen. As it is included in Python 3 standard library, your code could run on any machine that run Python 3 without pre-installing site-package

```
import urllib.request
url_request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
url_connect = urllib.request.urlopen(url_request)

#remember to open file in bytes mode
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    while True:
        buffer = url_connect.read(buffer_size)
        if not buffer: break

        #an integer value of size of written data
        data_wrote = f.write(buffer)

#you could probably use with-open-as manner
url_connect.close()
```

This answer provides a solution to HTTP 403 Forbidden when downloading file over http using Python. I have tried only requests and urllib modules, the other module may provide something better, but this is the one I used to solve most of the problems.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PycURL](http://pycurl.io/) on Python 2 and 3.

```
import pycurl

FILE_DEST = 'pycurl.html'
FILE_SRC = 'http://pycurl.io/'

with open(FILE_DEST, 'wb') as f:
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, FILE_SRC)
    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, f)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but for `python>=3.6` you can use:

```
import dload
dload.save(url)
```

---

Install `dload` with:

```
pip3 install dload
```

Comment: Can I ask - where does the file save once the program runs? Also, is there a way to name it and save it in a specific location?   This is the link I am working with - when you click the link it immediately downloads an excel file:    https://www.ons.gov.uk/generator?format=xls&uri=/economy/inflationandpriceindices/timeseries/chaw/mm23

Comment: You can supply the save location as second argument, e.g.: `dload.save(url, "/home/user/test.xls")`

Answer (score 3):

This may be a little late, But I saw pabloG's code and couldn't help adding a os.system('cls') to make it look AWESOME! Check it out :

```
    import urllib2,os

    url = "http://download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip"

    file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    f = open(file_name, 'wb')
    meta = u.info()
    file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
    print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)
    os.system('cls')
    file_size_dl = 0
    block_sz = 8192
    while True:
        buffer = u.read(block_sz)
        if not buffer:
            break

        file_size_dl += len(buffer)
        f.write(buffer)
        status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
        status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
        print status,

    f.close()
```

If running in an environment other than Windows, you will have to use something other then 'cls'. In MAC OS X and Linux it should be 'clear'.

Comment: `cls` doesn't do anything on my OS X or nor on an Ubuntu server of mine. Some clarification could be good.

Comment: I think you should use `clear` for linux, or even better replace the print line instead of clearing the whole command line output.

Comment: this answer just copies another answer and adds a call to a deprecated function (`os.system()`) that launches a subprocess to clear the screen using a  platform specific command (`cls`).  How does this have *any* upvotes?? Utterly worthless "answer" IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

New Api urllib3 based implementation

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> r = http.request('GET', 'your_url_goes_here')
>>> r.status
   200
>>> r.data
   *****Response Data****
```

More info: https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted do download all the files from a webpage. I tried `wget` but it was failing so I decided for the Python route and I found this thread.

After reading it, I have made a little command line application, [`soupget`](https://gist.github.com/gibbbone/acde8ec66ca76f59d70af6ebd8511252), expanding on the excellent answers of [PabloG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776/6332373) and [Stan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16518224/6332373) and adding some useful options.

It uses [BeatifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to collect all the URLs of the page and then download the ones with the desired extension(s). Finally it can download multiple files in parallel.

Here it is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import (division, absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals)
import sys, os, argparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# --- insert Stan's script here ---
# if sys.version_info >= (3,): 
#...
#...
# def download_file(url, dest=None): 
#...
#...

# --- new stuff ---
def collect_all_url(page_url, extensions):
    """
    Recovers all links in page_url checking for all the desired extensions
    """
    conn = urllib2.urlopen(page_url)
    html = conn.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all('a')

    results = []    
    for tag in links:
        link = tag.get('href', None)
        if link is not None: 
            for e in extensions:
                if e in link:
                    # Fallback for badly defined links
                    # checks for missing scheme or netloc
                    if bool(urlparse.urlparse(link).scheme) and bool(urlparse.urlparse(link).netloc):
                        results.append(link)
                    else:
                        new_url=urlparse.urljoin(page_url,link)                        
                        results.append(new_url)
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":  # Only run if this file is called directly
    # Command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Download all files from a webpage.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-u', '--url', 
        help='Page url to request')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-e', '--ext', 
        nargs='+',
        help='Extension(s) to find')    
    parser.add_argument(
        '-d', '--dest', 
        default=None,
        help='Destination where to save the files')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-p', '--par', 
        action='store_true', default=False, 
        help="Turns on parallel download")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Recover files to download
    all_links = collect_all_url(args.url, args.ext)

    # Download
    if not args.par:
        for l in all_links:
            try:
                filename = download_file(l, args.dest)
                print(l)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error while downloading: {}".format(e))
    else:
        from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
        results = ThreadPool(10).imap_unordered(
            lambda x: download_file(x, args.dest), all_links)
        for p in results:
            print(p)
```

An example of its usage is:

```sh
python3 soupget.py -p -e <list of extensions> -d <destination_folder> -u <target_webpage>
```

And an actual example if you want to see it in action:

```sh
python3 soupget.py -p -e .xlsx .pdf .csv -u https://healthdata.gov/dataset/chemicals-cosmetics
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is with built-in [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html):

```py
from http import HTTPStatus, client
from shutil import copyfileobj

# using https
connection = client.HTTPSConnection("www.example.com")
with connection.request("GET", "/noise.mp3") as response:
    if response.status == HTTPStatus.OK:
        copyfileobj(response, open("noise.mp3")
    else:
        raise Exception("request needs work")
```

The `HTTPConnection` object is considered “low-level” in that it performs the desired request once and assumes the developer will subclass it or script in a way to handle the nuances of HTTP. Libraries such as [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tend to handle more special cases such as automatically following redirects and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Options like:

1. `wget.download('url', file_name)`,
2. `urllib.urlretrieve ('url_to_file', file_name)`,

Have the flaw that it's not possible to setup User Agent. That may cause issues while downloading the files from external sites (they're blocking particular User Agents so you have to pass a custom one).

I found [urllib3](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/) much handy.

```py
import urllib3

resp = urllib3.request('GET', 'http://www.example.com/sound.mp3', preload_content=False, headers={'User-Agent': 'Customer User Agent If Needed'})

with open('sound.mp3', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in resp.stream(65536):
        f.write(chunk)

resp.release_conn()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `keras.utils.get_file` to do it:

```
from tensorflow import keras

path_to_downloaded_file = keras.utils.get_file(
    fname="file name",
    origin="https://www.linktofile.com/link/to/file",
    extract=True,
    archive_format="zip",  # downloaded file format
    cache_dir="/",  # cache and extract in current directory
)
```

Answer (score -4):

Another way is to call an external process such as curl.exe. Curl by default displays a progress bar, average download speed, time left, and more all formatted neatly in a table.
Put curl.exe in the same directory as your script

```
from subprocess import call
url = ""
call(["curl", {url}, '--output', "song.mp3"])
```

Note: You cannot specify an output path with curl, so do an os.rename afterwards